# Algorithm to find intersections between straight line

Tags: computational-geometry, line-intersection

I would like to find all intersections between straight line (infinite). I'm trying change the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm which works for set of line segments, but I have no idea how to represent infinite straight line properly. The first idea was to determine boundary points which would simulate start and end each of lines, but I suppose it's incorrect solution (how to find "infinite" points?). The next idea is to use equations to represent the straight lines, but I don't know if I can use Bentley-Ottmann algorithm (how to order lines and to add events to schedule?). What's more I probably need to use division to detect intersection of two lines (while solving a set of equations). I would like to avoid it.

Can you give me some advice?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Infinite lines are easy. Solve simultaneous equations that represent the lines. How many dimensions are you dealing with?

Comment: Use the 2 straight line equation y = mx + b; then solve!

Comment: What you are trying to solve is known as the line arrangement problem. Specific solutions are known, but not so easy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_lines#Algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this in 2-dimension Euclidean space, you are over-inflating your problem. High schoolers will tell you that lines can be represented by an equation:

```
y = m*x + b
```

But it can't represent a vertical line. You can use the more generic equation (see [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line.html)):

```
a*x + b*y = c
```

In two-dimension Euclidean space, two lines either:

- Have a single common point; or
- No common point: they are parallel to each other; or
- Have infinite numbers of common points: they are the same line.

The first 2 cases are an equation-solve away. The third case is true if:

```
a1/a2 == b1/b2
```

(of course you need to handle cases where `a2 = 0` or `b2 = 0`)

Comment: You meant "a*x+b*y+c=0"?

Answer (score 0):

Forget Bentley Ottman.  It's cleverness is for dealing with line *segments*, which you don't have.

If the lines are infinite, then *every pair* of non-parallel lines will have exactly one intersection.  So if {L1, L2, ... Ln} is the set of all lines, the algorithm is:

```
for Li, i = 1, 2, ... n-1
  for Lj, j = i+1, ... n
    if Li parallel to Lj, output <i, j, PARALLEL> 
    else output <i, j, intersection(Li, Lj)>
```

You could include a separate check to fine *coincident* parallel lines if that's useful.

The most robust way to store arbitrary lines is (as already mentioned), the coefficient triple:

```
<A, B, C>
```

such that Ax + By + C = 0.  It's handy and good practice to normalize so that A^2 + B^2 = 1.  Now [A,B] is the unit normal to the line.  With some vector math it's pretty easy to see that the intersection P of two lines g and h is given by a simple cross product:

```
P = [x/w, y/w], where [x,y,w] = [Ag, Bg, Cg] X [Ah, Bh, Ch]
```

Note that for parallel (including coincident) lines, you'll get w=0 so the division will fail as you'd expect.  You can use very small absolute `w` values to detect the parallel case above.  This is one reason to normalize [A, B].  It makes this test scale-independent.